# Regarding a Plugin for Eclipse to represent the table references on other table in eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse, db2

I am working on a java project which has it database in db2 and I connect to database through a common ip , I use the database view perspective of eclipse itself and see the table entries s in eclipse database explorer itself, But I was searching for a plugin in eclipse such that When I click on particular table then a screenshot of it referenced table in form of graph is to be get displayed that shows its references in other tables too..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use IBM Data Studio that is an Eclipse-based application, with many plugins, including the one that you want.
You can download it for free from http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html (Get Free Tools > Data Studio Full Client)
This is a very good tool to work with DB2 from Eclipse.